# UITextfield validation in swift4 - Dynamic cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a Form (tableview with questions and textfields).
It is not static as data may change depending upon the form user select.
So I store these questions and validation constraints in a dictionary.
How can I validate these fields before user press submit ?
Code is given below :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let Cell:FormTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellformid") as! FormTableViewCell
    let dict = questions?[indexPath.row]
        Cell.form_question_label.text = dict?.question_name
        Cell.form_answer_textfield.text = dict?.answer ?? ""
        return Cell
    }

//Submit Button Action
   @IBAction func saveFormButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
   //Here I do operations to save a Array which contain all attended answers.

}
```

NOTE : When I press submit button data entered by user is being saved to database, but Validation cannot be done,because if some question is unattended that is not stored in database and also is not attached to the Array. So I cannot check whether all Mandatory fields are completed.

Please suggest a method..

Comment: do you want logic to validate form? I am not able to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @George Validation for my form. Pls see the answer Mateusz provided and my comment.. hope you'll understand. Sorry if Iam not clear!

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your `UITextField`:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

and then validate answers:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
   //Validation
}
```

Comment: This works only if Textfield is changed or edited. What happens if user haven't entered anything or textFieldDidChange() is not invoked at all ?

Comment: If `UITextField` isn't edit or change you can also read value for proper `UITextField` directly by `textField.text`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
     if (view is UITextField) {
          var textfield = view as! UITextField
          if (textfield.text == "") {
                // execute code
          }
     }
}
```